# TFS Build - Specific folders for executable solutions

Tags: tfs

I recently had to create a set of TFS Builds for many solutions and I have come across a strange behavior:

I have two solutions that contains exclusively Library projects (including unit tests projects) and console applications. When I created the builds for those solutions, I did specify /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true​ in the process as an MSBuild Argument. But when the build is finished, all of the outputs from all of the project are in the same folder instead of being in a specific folder for each projects.

The strange thing is, it did work for solutions that were created as Web Projets first. Perhaps am I missing something ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: The solutions are in .NET 4.5 and we are using TFS Server 2012.